# Jinja2 - sum legnth of list in object in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have an object

```
def class A:
    @property
    def some_list(self):
        return some_kind_of_list
```

So I have a list of objects of type `A`,`my_list`.

I wanted to know if it's possible, with Jinja2 methods and filters only, to get the sum of lengthes of all lists `some_list` in all objects `A` in my list.

I tried it out with some `my_list|attr('some_list')|length|sum`, or `my_list|attr(some_list.__len__)|sum`, and also `my_list|map(attribute='some_list')|length|sum` but none seems to work.

Can it be done using only the Jinja2 methods and filters? or is it too complicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
mylist|map(attribute='somelist')|map('length')|sum
```

You need to:

- Extract the `somelist` attribute from all the items in `mylist`
- Call the `length` filter on each list
- Finally, sum up all the lengths